# How to mark a product as New in magento?

Tags: magento-1.9, labels

Is there a way to make a product have a little label next to it saying 'New'. I noticed there is an option in the general settings of a product to set the dates for which it is new so how would I go about having a little label next to it saying "new"?

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up a new Attribute in Catalogue -> Attributes -> Manage Attributes . Set is as a boolean, give it an id of new_product. Make it available on the front end product view (one of the advanced options).

Now add the attribute to your custom attribute set if your using one, or the default set if you are not. Go to product edit section and set it to ‘Yes’ for your product and save it.

So we’ve got a product in the Magento catalogue which has a boolean flag set to yes for the attribute ‘new_product’.

In your template files (templates/catalog/product/list.phtml and templates/catalog/product/view/media.phtml) you’d find the spot where the images are loaded and add in a conditional statement which checks the product model for the attribute and then adds some html is if finds it set to ‘Yes’.

```
 <div class="product-image">

        <?php if($_product->getNewProduct()) { ?>
            <div class="new-product"></div>
        <?php } ?>

        <?php
            $_img = '<img id="image" src="'.$this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'image').'" alt="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" title="'.$this->htmlEscape($this->getImageLabel()).'" />';
            echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_img, 'image');
        ?>
</div>
```

Then you have to write the css to display the new label properly on product image. Css will be somthing like this -

```
.products-grid .product-image { position: relative; display:block; width:244px; height:156px; margin:0 0 10px; }
.new-product {
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 65px;
    height: 66px;
    display: block;
    z-index: 2;
    background: url(../images/new-product.png) no-repeat;
}
```